# Replace/Rearrange/Swap words in string based on first number in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table containing a column "Description"

This column has multiple rows like this:

```
Heartxxx 03-0 ww wwwq
Heart Child 75-0 qweq
Legxxxxxxww 08-0 qaew
```

What I need is the "word" chars consisting of 4 chars starting from the first number to be in the beginning of the string. So expected results:

```
03-0 Heartxxx ww wwwq
75-0 Heart Child qweq
08-0 Legxxxxxxww qaew
```

Is this possible and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most probably product specific functions will be used here.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL I bobbed this snippet together using substring, patindex & concat.

No physical tables were created.

```
 create table #str_twist(str_orig nvarchar(255), Str_twist nvarchar(255))


insert into #str_twist(str_orig) values ('Heartxxx 03-0 ww wwwq'), ('Heart Child 75-0 qweq'), ('Legxxxxxxww 08-0 qaew')


select * into #TBLFormat from(
SELECT SUBSTRING(str_orig,(SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%',str_orig)),5) as a,
PAtindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%',str_orig)  as b,
replace(str_orig, (SUBSTRING(str_orig,(SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]%',str_orig)),5)),'') as c
FROM #str_twist)a

select * , concat(A,c)as d from #TBLFormat
```

Sorry it looks  awful  but after running I got this

[image: Result]

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres you can use a combination of `substring()` and `regexp_replace()`

```
select substring(the_column from '[0-9-]{4}') || ' '|| regexp_replace(the_column, '[0-9-]{4}\s', '')
from the_table;
```

This:

```
with the_table (the_column) as (
  VALUES
    ('Heartxxx 03-0 ww wwwq'),
    ('Heart Child 75-0 qweq'),
    ('Legxxxxxxww 08-0 qaew')
)
select the_column, 
       substring(the_column from '[0-9-]{4}') || ' '|| regexp_replace(the_column, '[0-9-]{4}\s', '') as new_word
from the_table;
```

Returns:

```
the_column            | new_word             
----------------------+----------------------
Heartxxx 03-0 ww wwwq | 03-0 Heartxxx ww wwwq
Heart Child 75-0 qweq | 75-0 Heart Child qweq
Legxxxxxxww 08-0 qaew | 08-0 Legxxxxxxww qaew
```